# Client/server templating systems that allow wrapping content without {{#open_tag}} and {{#close_tag}}?

Tags: javascript, templates, mustache, handlebars.js

My Web application is currently using Tapestry 5.2.6. I want to write a new feature with the following requirements:

- Users can click on items in a gallery to see a lightbox showing a detailed view, including description, comments, seller controls if they have the right credentials, and the ability to buy without leaving the page.
- The url should be updated to reflect whether they're in gallery view or details view.
- URL changes should be dynamic in browsers that support HTML5 pushState. Full page refreshes are acceptable in older browsers.
- Both the gallery page and the details page must be crawlable - users without Javascript should see a fully marked up page.
- Speed - needs to be much faster than I know I can expect from Tapestry.

My plan is to choose and implement a template language that can evaluate equally well on the server or on the client. For the initial page load, I can render the template on the server. For subsequent updates, I can pass the item's viewmodel object as JSON to the client and evaluate the template there.

So far so good. The problem is that none of the template languages I've looked at are powerful enough to feel good about moving toward for the future. As a case study, consider that out of the following:

- Mustache
- dust
- Hogan
- Handlebars

None seem to have the power to do a "wrapping" transformation like this:

```
# base template
{>widget}
    <span class="content">Hello world</span>
{/widget}

# widget template
<div class="widget">
    {>widget_body/}
</div>

# rendered output
<div class="widget">
    <span class="content">Hello world</span>
</div>
```

Notice that the wrapped content is taken from the base template, and the output of the widget template surrounds it on both sides. The only way I know to achieve this in the above languages would be a template something like:

```
{>open_widget/}
    {>widget_body/}
{>close_widget/}
```

Which means two templates for every component, an opener and a closer, both containing unclosed tags. (In fairness, dust can do this somewhat elegantly using blocks and inline partials, but because inline partials are global to the template, you're limited to one use of the widget per template.)

My questions about templates are these:

- I know that industry leaders like LinkedIn and Twitter are using these technologies and doing great. Am I asking too much? If you've used one of them, how did you deal with the "wrapping problem"?
- A few solutions I've investigated do appear to support it: jquery-tmpl, which is no longer officially maintained; underscore and ejs, which make me nervous as a long term solution with their embedded code; and Closure templates. Currently Closure looks the best to me, to my surprise! If you've used any of these, what were your findings?

Comment: Do you want other features besides the "wrapping," or is that enough? I wrote a simple solution that does exactly what you're talking about as far as wrapping, but nothing else. It's very lightweight, like 50 LOC. I can post it if you're interested in a minimal solution.

Comment: It's something I'd like, and consider reasonable, and is rarer than I expected and thus makes a good test of language power. If your code does do exactly what I'm talking about then I'd be interested to see it. Can it be integrated with an existing template language?

Comment: After rereading your post, I'm not sure if this is really what you want, or the reverse of what you want. Take a look at [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WLxJW/) and let me know if it's what you had in mind, if so I'll write a proper answer.

Comment: Functionally that's exactly what I'm asking about. If you want to expand on it I'd be glad to know what motivated you to build a mini-template language just for that feature and how you're using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether anything out there does what you're talking about. I needed something similar and figured writing a simple text replacement script would be quicker than comparing existing solutions and learning to use one.

This script is not production ready (should be tested more, and the API is weird), but it should give you an idea of one way it can be done.

Here's how it's set up:

---

**Storing templates in the document**

The template text is stored in script tags with a `type` attribute other than "text/javascript". Each template has a unique id attribute.

```
<script id="some_template" type="text/plain">

    a valid template

</script>
```

Browsers should not render these. Any characters are allowed (except `</script>`), and nothing needs to be escaped.

---

**Placeholders**

Placeholders look like this: `{@some_identifier}`.

```
<script id="image_template" type="text/plain">

    <a href="{@img_url}"><img src="{@img_url}"></a>

</script>
```

Each placeholder will be replaced with either:

- a value passed in from another template,
- an argument passed to a JavaScript function when getting a copy of the template, or
- an empty string if no replacement value was found.

---

**Including one template in another**

The `@@` "pseudotag" includes the contents of another template in the current template.

```
<script id="photo_template" type="text/plain">

    <@@ image_template></@@>

    <div class="photo-caption">{@caption}</div>

</script>
```

`photo_template` includes  `image_template`. All inclusion replacement happens before any placeholder replacement, so `photo_template` has `{@img_url}` and `{@caption}` placeholders.

---

**Inclusion with placeholder replacement**

This is where the "wrapping" comes from. Ideally, placeholders will almost always be replaced by content from other templates, rather than values passed in when getting a copy  of the template.

```
<script id="missing_photo_template" type="text/plain">

    <@@ photo_template>
        <@ img_url>notfound.png</@>
    </@@>

</script>
```

`missing_photo_template` includes `photo_template`, providing it with a replacement for `{@img_url}`, so `missing_photo_template` has only the `{@caption}` placeholder.

---

**JavaScript**

The API sucks right now, but essentially the main namespace `at` has two functions, `txt` and `node`. The first one gets a copy of a template as text, the second one gets a copy as an Element (which means it should have one root node, unlike some of my examples above).

Here it is:

```
/**

    Atrocious Templates

*/
var at = (function(){

  var rTemplate = /<@@\s*(.*?)>((?:[\w\W](?!<@@))*?)<\/@@>/gm,
      rOption = /<@\s*(.*?)>([\w\W]*?)<\/@>/gm,
      rValue = /\{@(.*?)\}/g,
      rTag = /<(\w+)/i,
      rSpace = /\s+/,
      templates = {},
      doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument('');

  /** 

      Inlcude inner templates.

      @private

      @param {string} m0
          The full inclusion text.

      @param {string} m1
          The ID of the included template.

      @param {string} m2
          Values passed to included template.

      @return {string} 

  */
  function includeTemplates(m0, m1, m2) {
    var opts = {};
    m2.replace(rOption, function(m0, m1, m2) { opts[m1] = m2; });
    return txt(m1, opts, true);
  }

  /** 

      Get text contents of a template.

      @private

      @param {string} id
          The ID of the template.

      @return {string} 

  */
  function get(id) {
    if (templates[id]) return templates[id];
    var last, t = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
    while (last != t && (last = t)) t = t.replace(rTemplate, includeTemplates);
    return (templates[id] = t);
  }

  /** 

      Get a text copy of a template.

      @param {string} id
          The ID of the template.

      @param {Object.<string|function ():string>} options
          Properties of this object will replace placeholder tokens.
          Each property can be either a string, or a function which 
          returns a string.

      @param {boolean=} noStrip
          By default, placeholders for which no replacement text is 
          found are removed. Setting this to `true` overrides that
          behavior, leaving non-replaced placeholders intact. 

      @return {string} 

  */
  function txt(id, options, noStrip) {
    if (!options) options = {};
    return get(id).replace(rValue, function(m0, m1) {
      var v = options[m1];
      return noStrip && !v && m0 || v && (v.call ? v() : v) || '';
    });
  }

  /** 

      Get a node copy of a template.

      @param {string} id
          The ID of the template.

      @param {Object.<string|function ():string>} options
          Properties of this object will replace placeholder tokens.

      @return {string} 

  */
  function node(id, options) {
    var text = txt(id, options),
        root = text.match(rTag)[1];
    doc.open; doc.write(text); doc.close();
    return doc.getElementsByTagName(root)[0];
  }

  // exports

  return { txt: txt, node: node };

}());
```

Again, I'm not recommending you use this in production as it hasn't been tested much (although it seems to work fine), but hopefully this will give you some ideas about how what you want can be accomplished.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at handlebarjs.com - I'm using it on both the server and client.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the question is old, but doesn't Mustache support *partials*?

http://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html

> ...In this way you may want to think of partials as includes, or template
>   expansion, even though it's not literally true.
>
> For example, this template and partial:
>
> **base.mustache**:
>
> ```
> <h2>Names</h2> {{#names}}   {{> user}} {{/names}}
> ```
>
> **user.mustache**:
>
> ```
> <strong>{{name}}</strong>
> ```
>
> Can be thought of as a single, expanded template:
>
> ```
> <h2>Names</h2> {{#names}}   <strong>{{name}}</strong> {{/names}}
> ```